# How to create fontawesome local template in vue js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create a local fontawesome model to be able to import it into my vuejs application, but I'm not succeeding, could someone help me?

`fontawesome.js

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { faUserSecret } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(faUserSecret)

export default [library, FontAwesomeIcon, faUserSecret] 


main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

import './assets/main.css'


import library from './models/fontAwesome'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)
app.component('font-awesome-icon', library)
app.mount('#app')`your text``
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating a Vue plugin. Hope this help.

```js
Icon.js

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faUserSecret } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

export default {
  install(Vue){
     library.add(faUserSecret)
     Vue.component('FaIcon', FontAwesomeIcon)
  }
}

main.js
import Icon from '/path/to/Icon.js'
.
.
.

app.use(Icon)
```